# Custom 'fold' function needs counter

Tags: haskell, counter, fold

My homework went really well until I stumpled upon the last task.
First, I had to define a custom `List` structure:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving Show
```

Another task was to write a custom `fold` function:

```
foldList :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
foldList f b Nil        = b
foldList f b (Cons a l) = f a (foldList f b l)
```

*The second parameter is the value that is used at the end of the list (at a `Nil` element).*

I also had to write a function `prodList` that multiplies every element of the provided list with each other:

```
prodList :: List Int -> Int
prodList = foldList (\x y -> x * y) 1
```

*The `1` at the end is the neutral element of multplication. It therefore has no effect on the calculation.*

The last one, though, is hard for me to solve.
I have to write a function `binList` that calculates the decimal value of list that represents a binary number. The least significant bit is the first element of the list, the binary number is therefore reversed.
A given example is that the result of `binList (Cons 1 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 0 (Cons 1 Nil)))))` should be 19 (since (10001)_2 is (19)_10). The result of the list [1,1,0,1], however, should be (1011)_2=(11)_10).
The culprit of the assignment is, that we *have* to use `foldList`.

I know how to calculate each digit, but I struggle to find a way to find out which index `i` I'm currently at:

```
binList :: List Int -> Int
binList = foldList (\x y -> 2^i*x + y)
```

There probably is a nice, curry way to solve this in Haskell. Could you explain to me how you would solve this assignment?

Comment: You don't need to know what index you are at. (Hint: If you have 10 digits, the most significant needs to be multiplied by 2, 9 times... thats the number of digits to the right of it in the list.. hmm....)

Comment: The function is applied on a per element basis. The exponent `i` changes for each of the list's elements. I have no idea how it's possible to do that without knowing the index to determine the exponent.

Comment: o.O That's so easy! Thanks for the hint! Totally forgot that way of doing it! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were to write out the calculation, it would look like this:

```
x0 + 2 * x1 + 4 * x2 + 8 * x3 + ...
```

This might suggest you need to use the index, but if you factorize this expression, you get this instead:

```
x0 + 2 * (x1 + 2 * (x2 + 2 * (x3 ...
```

Do you see how it can be written as a fold now?  Notice that there is a self-similarity that looks kind of like this:

```
x + 2 * x'
```

Hopefully that's enough of a hint for you :)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! @alternative already gave this hint and I just wrote the code. This works! Sometimes I just don't see the wood for the trees. :D